# How to open second lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, lightbox

Is there a way to open the second lightbox internally? Currently, the way I'm opening, it opens over to the top of each other.

What I'm trying to do is similar to this;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6crh7.jpg

Here is my code;

```css
.product1 {display: none}
.product2 {display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/featherlight/1.5.0/featherlight.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/featherlight/1.5.0/featherlight.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href=".product1" class="" data-featherlight>See product detail</a>

<div class="lightbox product1">
  <h1>Product name</h1>
  <p><b>Description:</b></p>
  <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
  <br><br>
  <p><b>Related products:</b></p>
  <a href=".product2" class="" data-featherlight>Click Me</a>
</div>

<div class="lightbox product2">
  <h1>Product name</h1>
  <p><b>Description:</b></p>
  <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed `beforeOpen: $.noop,` inside **featherlight.js** to `beforeOpen: function() { $.featherlight.close() },` and it worked.